# How can I keep playing Call of Duty WaW Zombies when the game window loses focus?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war, cod-world-at-war-zombies

I play Call of Duty WaW Zombies in a window with a xbox 360 controller. When the window loses focus, however, the game stops picking up controller inputs.

Is there anyway to keep the gaming getting my inputs from my controller when is not the active window?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

Like any program, CoD WaW only gets inputs if the window is the active one -- regardless if you play with a controller or not.

In the end the controller just sends key strokes to the game, thus resulting in actions in the game. So if the game loses focus, the key strokes sent by the controller just are received by the focused window.

As far as I know multiple windows can't be active at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a program called [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to send to a certain window/application/process.

You could bind each of the inputs from the controller to a function in your script which would send the same input to the game window.

[See here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) for more detail on how to use `ControlSend`.